# Synonym request: lol-dominion

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I just saw the [lol-dominion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lol-dominion). As it is a game mode, I suggest to merge it to the game it refers to : [league-of-legends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/league-of-legends).

I do not think we have [cod4-ffa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cod4-ffa) or other like that for each type of game.

(Or maybe we should make game-modes tags like ctf, ffa, ... ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only 8 questions, and I don't see the harm, so merge performed.